# Retrieve database content based on dates and default to 7 days record

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to display records from the database and default them to weekly records.
e.g I want to have the records to default to Ist of Nov 2013 - 7th of Nov 2013 (That's a week from now) then on clicking the previous link  25th of Oct - 31st of Oct (2013) and the next link 8th of Nov - 14th of Nov (2013)

**I am using php and CodeIgniter. Any help or link to a page that can help me will be appreciated.**

All am doing now is to display all records and use pagination to display 7 fields per page but I need to display per week and default to the current week from Friday to Thursday..

```
public function index()
{
    //Count all records
    $shopID= $this->uri->segment(2);
    session_id($shopID);
    $this->db->where('BDP_COST_CENTRE_NUMBER', $shopID);
    $count =  $this->db->count_all_results('WHOUSE1.DLY_BWR_DLY_PERFORMANCE');
    //Set up pagination
    $perpage = 7;
    if ($count > $perpage)
    {
        $config['base_url'] = 'http://bwr/index.php/daily_shop_performance/' . $shopID . '/';
        $config['total_rows'] = $count;
        $config['per_page'] = $perpage;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $this->data['pagination']=$this->pagination->create_links();
        $offset = $this->uri->segment(3);
    } else {
        $this->data['pagination']='';
        $offset = 0;
    }
    $shopID= $this->uri->segment(2);
    $this->db->where('BDP_COST_CENTRE_NUMBER', $shopID);
    $this->db->limit($perpage, $offset);
    **$this->data['shops_performances'] = $this->performance_m->get();**
    $this->data['subview'] = 'page/performance_page';
    $this->load->view('_layout_main', $this->data);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: How are your records stored when brought in from the database, or is each click a new query? And do you always want the week to count as just 7days back?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a pagination method based on record's date.

First you need store record's date as timestamp integer to avoid problems and be free to change date format and make calculations.

On where clause you need something like this (if you're usign seven days interval):

```
public function getRecords($start, $interval = 7)
{
    $limit = (24 * 60 *60) * $interval;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE record_date > $start AND record_date < interval";
}
```

I need see your code, for more specific help...
My code was generic example, use CodeIgniter query builder instead.